# Audi a4 b6 bonnet sensor warning on dash

Tags: electrical, audi, sensor, a4

Can anyone help with the bonnet open on dash. How and where is it best to bypass the sensor. If the wires are left open still have warning and if tied together still have warning? Do i need to bridge the wires in the connector by passenger headlamp connector? Any help would be appreciated as cannot rid of the warning on the dash. Audi a4 b6 2003

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: If the wires have a short somewhere it won't make any difference if you tie them.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. _Why_ are you looking to replace the sensor? Has it failed? Is there some other issue that you're looking to resolve? Just bypassing the sensor for the fun of it doesn't seem likely...